# Выборка колонок по массиву

Tags: массивы, sql-server

у меня есть таблица с колонками а1,а2,а3 и т.д. до 50. возможно ли написать выборку, где в where части не перечисляя все эти поля дать поиск по массиву а[1-50]= ?

Answer (score 1):

НЕТ... именно в запросе так нельзя сделать... Но можно написать конструктор запроса который допустим по такому выражению будет формировать соответствующий запрос

```
$qwery_str = full(1,50);
function fuul(int i, int j)
{
   for(int x=i; x<=j;x++)
   {
      //тут формирование строки запроса
   }
}
```

ну ещё можно написать перечень названий полей но это уже ваша фантазия.

Answer (score 0):

Если эти поля имеют хранят текстовую информацию и поиск по ним идет, например, по LIKE тогда как вариант можно создать полнотекстовый индекс по этим полям и использовать CONTAINS (поля при этом не придется перечислять). Если такой возможности нет тогда можно сделать одно поле, в которое занести все данные из столбцов и искать по нему. Это что касается хранения и поиска текстовой информации.

Для остального в голову приходит такой вариант - если столбы имеют одно и тоже название и отличаются только номером в конце и идут по порядку тогда можно в цикле сделать динамический запрос.